# Writing custom atoi() function

Tags: c, argv, atoi, argc

I am trying to write a c code that mulplies two numbers and I wrote a custom `atoi() function` to convert char to int. I tried running the `exe file` with the following arguments ./exe 2 3 but it giving me a result of 0 instead of 6 and I can't seem to find where the bug in my code is coming from.
here is a snippet of me code

```
 int myatoi(char* str)
{
        int i = 0, result = 0, sign = 1, flag;
/** Chheck for whitespce*/
        while (str[i] == ' ')
                i++;
/**Check for sign of the first num*/
        if (str[i] == '-')
        {
                sign = -1;
                i++;
        }
        for (; str[i] !='\0'; i++)
        {
                if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                {
                        result = result * 10 + (str[i] - '0');
                        flag = 1;
                        if (str[i + 1] < '0' || str[i + 1] > '9')
                        {
                                flag = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
                return (0);
        return (sign * result);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, result = 1;

        if (argc < 2)
        {
                printf("Error\n");
                return (1);
        }
        for (i = 1; i  < argc; i++)
        {
                result = result * myatoi(argv[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", result);

        return (0);
}
```

Comment: `str[i + 1] < '0'` will be true for `'\0'`, which is smaller than any other character.

Comment: ...so `flag` will always be set to `0` at the end of the input. Also note that `int flag` is not always set to any value by all control paths.

Comment: (1) You forgot to initialize `flag`, so its value will be unspecified if you encounter a string with no digits, and (2) The look-ahead check for a non-digit inside the loop will always force `flag` to zero when the last digit is reached, so it if any digit is present, it will always return `0`.

Comment: even after I initialized flag to 0, i sill get 0 after i run the code with same arguments.

Comment: I don't think you need to look ahead inside the loop - it's more complicated than it needs to be. After the loop, just check that the next character is `'\0'`. `for (; isdigit(str[i]); i++)` will do all that work for you.

Comment: i think this would be a good time to try out the debugger.

Comment: don't forget that `atoi("17a")` will return `17`, not `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/zbjz87EqG

Comment: @AugustaFidelix You seem to have missed the main problem.  It was pointed out multiple times above.  Here's a concrete example:  Suppose the last digit in your number is `'5'`, followed by a null character `'\0'`.  In your loop, you will multiply `result` by `10` and then add `5`.  That part is fine.  But you will then look at the next character, which is `'\0'`.  That's not in the range of a digit character, so you incorrectly set `flag` to `0` and exit the loop.  You then return `0`.  Do you see why that's a bug?